# Why is my blob reading as an array?

Tags: php, ajax, audio, mysqli, blob

I have an HTML5 audio recorder which produces an audio blob (recorder.js by Matt Diamond) and executes a jquery ajax call to my PHP file.

```
function audioUpload() {

    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        //first look at the blob
        console.log(blob);

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('audioBlob', blob);
        var audioBlob = fd.get('audioBlob');

        //second look at the blob
        console.log(audioBlob);

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            data: fd,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            url: "audioSend.php",
        }).done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          })
    });
```

There are two console.log functions here that report the blob:

In the first, the console reads as a blob. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90zrb.png) In another part of the code I create an object URL with this and can play the audio using an HTML5 audio tag, so it's working.

In the second, the console reads it as a file. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyOfU.png) I can understand this, as blobs are file-like objects by definition. Still, I'm not sure why it isn't reported as a blob like the first instance.

The formData object is posted to audioSend.php where I get the value and insert it into my DB.

```
$audioBlob = $_FILES['audioBlob'];

$results = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO audioLog (audio) VALUES ('$audioBlob')");

echo ($audioBlob);
```

Attempting to insert the blob value into my DB throws an "Array to String Conversion" error, and echoing $audioBlob confirms that it is read as an array. The value shown in my MYSQL DB Blob column is only a few bytes as a result, and not the much larger audio blob object that I want.

Why is the blob read as an array, and how can I get the REAL blob value be inserted into my DB?

Comment: FYI - when you run into issues like this in future, `print_r()` is your friend.

Comment: `print_r()` is never your friend, but `var_dump()` is. :P

Comment: @Sammitch var_dump() also confirms that the value of $audioBlob is an array, just as I saw in the echo().

Answer (score 0):

You are POSTing the data, so access it via $_POST:

```
$audioBlob = $_POST['audioBlob'];
```

Also, use prepared statements as you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: +1 for prepared statments. Would like to note that particularly large blobs may need special consideration for storage and retrieval, eg: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php Alternatively, put the blob data into a file and store the path to that file in the database.

Comment: I get no values at all (_null_) when using $_POST. What work I've seen uploading objects suggests $_FILES instead. Like I said, it is there, but it is read as an array instead of an object.

 
@Sammitch The blobs I'm uploading are no more than 300 kilobytes at this point, though size will be a consideration later. I may go the file server route if I can't figure this out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a second look at your code and, while I'm no JS programmer, it looks like you've disabled any sort of graceful POST and have just crammed the raw data into a POST request.

If you want to get this data you'll have to open the `php://input` stream which contains the un-processed POST body. Eg:

```
$f_in = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
$f_out = fopen($APPROOT.'/files/foo.bin', 'wb');
while( ! feof($f_in) ) {
    $buf = fread($f_in, 4096);
    fwrite($f_out, $buf);
}
fclose($f_in);
fclose($f_out);
```

Which will write the POST data to the file `$APPROOT.'/files/foo.bin'` 4KB at a time without cramming the entire thing into memory first.

If you want to upload it as a file and have it available in `$_FILES` you'll have to look into how to properly upload a file via whatever JS library that is.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code I'm using is the recommended method for uploading files in Jquery, the JS library I'm using. 

Thanks for your help. I'll look into the input stream and see if there's something there.